# $\frac{w_k}{x-x_k}$ expansion into decreasing powers of $x$

Tags: calculus, power-series

How can $\dfrac {(w_k)}{(x-x_k)}$ becomes:$$\dfrac {w_k}x+\dfrac {w_kx_k}{x^2}+\dfrac {w_kx_k^2}{x^3}+...$$
I couldnt figured out the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can use this:
$$\dfrac 1 {1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
For $|x| <1$ and note that you have:
$$\dfrac {w_k}{(x-x_k)}=\dfrac {w_k}{x}\dfrac {1}{(1-x_k/x)}$$